# #include <string> but identifier still not found

Tags: c++, string, include

I am trying to use a string to hold a player name. when i type

```
#include <string>
```

this works correctly, and the VS2010 even autofills the text. Then i try to use a string, but i get an identifier not found:

```
#include <string.h>

class Player{
    string name;
int playerIndex;
    int position;
public:
    Player(string name, int index, int pos);
    void move();

};
```

On another note, the same thing (or similer is happening with vector)

```
#include <vector>

vector<cell> vBoard;
```

error: Vector is not a template

Comment: Use `std::string`, `std::vector`

Comment: I read that post before i posted my question.  And it does not seem to apply. When i try to use std::string i get the error "name following :: must be a class or namespace"

Comment: it was not a duplicate. The problem was the #include <string.h> should have been #include <string>.  I dont know exactly what the difference is but it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything in the C++ library is in the namespace `std`, so that it doesn't pollute the global namespace. You you need to qualify the names:

```
std::string name;
std::vector<cell> board;
```

You're also using the wrong header name; you want `<string>` not `<string.h>`.

Comment: first thing i tried... didnt work.

Comment: @Special--k: How didn't it work? Are you including the right header (as I've just added to the answer)?

Comment: More specifically, when i type std::string i get the error "name followed by :: must be a class"

Comment: @Special--k: Well, it should work if you fix both errors, as demonstrated [here](http://ideone.com/dnvMFI). If your compiler can't find `std::string` when you include `<string>` (**not** `<string.h>`), then there must be something wrong with your installation.

Comment: It was the header. i dont know what the difference is between <string.h> and <string> but that worked.

Comment: `<string.h>` is the header file for the legacy C string library (where strings are represented as NULL-terminated arrays of characters and operated on through a collection of functions in the global namespace). `<cstring>` moves the contents of `<string.h>` into the `std` namespace, but essentially retains the old functionality. `<string>` is the header file for the C++ string class.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the namespace

```
using namespace std;
```

or try

```
std::string
```